# Using !! to access bash history inside a Git alias

Tags: bash, git

I want to create an alias that runs `git stash` and then executes the command that was before it.

This would be useful when git doesn't allow to run a command with unsaved changes, such as checkout, rebase, etc.

What I've tried:

`s = "!git stash && fc -s`

`s = "!bash -c \"git stash && !!\""`

None of the above work. It looks like in the first one git creates a subshell to run this command, as fc outputs `no command found`.
The second one is similar, but here I explicitly create a subshell and it obviously doesn't work, with no access to the history.

Is there a way around this? It's likely that this could be accomplished with a bash alias, but I'd prefer to do it through a git alias.

Comment: Keep in mind that when git spawns bash, it's a different copy of bash than the one that started git. No in-process state (like history) is shared.

Comment: ...by contrast, of course, bash itself has direct access to its own history, which is why implementing this inside bash is the only approach that doesn't introduce a huge amount of complexity and general fragility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's likely that this could be accomplished with a bash alias,

Yes, this would be simple and robust.

> but I'd prefer to do it through a git alias.

Given how ugly and fragile this would be, I doubt it. However, here you go:

First, you need to relay the history. Make your shell write it out to the history file after every command by adding this to your `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

You can then add your `git` alias. It needs to

1. run with Bash, since the system `sh` may not support history expansion
2. enable history and history expansion
3. read the history file
4. use history expansion in a separate parsing unit (e.g. after a linefeed, outside a compound command):

So all in all:

```
s = "!bash -c 'set -Ho history; history -r ~/.bash_history\ngit stash && !-1'"
```

Note that it'll run the last command executed *regardless of bash instance*, so if you use multiple tmux/screen/terminal windows, it won't necessarily run the last command in your current shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a git alias to access the Bash history (or any other shell data for that matter), since the command after the exclamation mark is not run as a subshell. Git is an external command, so all its child processes are also not subshells.

#### More details

You can confirm this by setting a git alias `foo = !echo $$ $BASHPID` and comparing it with the current shell:

```
$ echo $$ $BASHPID
11461 11461
$ git foo
25437
```

In my case it's not even running Bash. After some testing I think it's running /bin/sh, which is Dash for me since I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: *run as a new process, not a subshell* A subshell **is** a subprocess (i.e., a new process) too.

Comment: @phd "External command" - that's the word I was trying to find. Edited!